# How to open most recent directory using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

For example, when I add a vector layer, next time that I want to add another layer it opens up where I chose my last layer from. How would one implement this in Python and/or PyQgis? I'm writing a plugin, and I want user to select layers in the same way as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using a combination of QSettings and a custom file-dialog.

To the `QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()` dialog a base directory can be passed. So you just need to configure a filter (Only shapefiles) and a base-directory. To get the last-used ones you can just query (`lastUsedDir()`) them from a QSettingsFile using the functions below. 
After file(s) have been selected, just query the basename of those files ( `os.path.basename`) and call `setLastUsedDir()` to set this value as attribute.

```
def lastUsedDir():
  settings = QSettings( "Your PluginName", "short-name" )
  return settings.value( "lastUsedDir", str( "" ) )

def setLastUsedDir( lastDir ):
  path = QFileInfo( lastDir ).absolutePath()
  settings = QSettings( "Your PluginName", "short-name" )
  settings.setValue( "lastUsedDir", str( path ) )
```